# нужен скаляр, но не понимаю, что делать

Tags: математика

[image]

Не получается написать функцию

Comment: Вот бы люди смотрели как выглядит их вопрос после того, как отправили его. Мечты, мечты...

Comment: Какой мат. пакет используете?

Comment: Похоже на MatCAD, но не уверен

Answer (score 1):

Возвести в квадрат можно число, а Вы пытаетесь возвести в квадрат некое неизвестное sin. В том виде, как у Вас это написано sin не является функцией от параметра. Должно быть записано примерно вот так (извините, форму записи Вашего мат-пакета я здесь не воспроизведу):

```
(sin(3*x))^2
```